# Are the Push Notifications APIs in Chrome and Firefox OS implementations of the same standard?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Are the Push Notifications APIs in Chrome and Firefox OS implementations of the same standard? If not, is any of them on the road to standardization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Push API that Chrome and Firefox both support is documented in the MDN [Using the Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API) how-to, which is the web-standard [Push API](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/), which in turn relies on web-standard [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), including the [showNotification(…)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) method for the web-standard [Notification API](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/).

The HTML5Rocks [Push Notifications on the Open Web](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web) how-to gives details on using the Web Push API; as it outlines, the basic cross-browser steps (just to crib that how-to’s headings) are:

- Register a Service Worker
- Set up the initial state
- Subscribe to Push Messaging
- Set up a Service Worker push event listener
- Send a push message

There are other steps that can vary depending on which browser the code is running in.